# Unexpected extra animation in Java

Tags: java, animation

http://pastebin.com/PXLFJjNG

I'm trying to figure out threading and animations so I made this really basic program where you can press buttons to move a rectangle up and down. The problem is that if you keep pressing the UP button till the rectangle reaches the top of the screen there's suddenly an extra blue rectangle.

This problem is kinda hard to explain just run the program and keep pressing UP and when you get to the top there's suddenly 2 rectangles being drawn. Is it a problem with my paint component?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class RectangleMovement implements Runnable {
    JFrame frame;
    MyPanel panel;
    private int x = 100;
    private int y = 100;
    private int playerX = 400;
    private int playerY = 350;
    private int horizontalGoal = 0;
    private int verticalGoal = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            new RectangleMovement().go();

    }

    private void go() {
            frame = new JFrame("Worst Game Ever");
            panel = new MyPanel();
            MyPanel buttonPanel = new MyPanel();
            JButton left = new JButton("Left");
            JButton right = new JButton("Right");
            JButton down = new JButton("Down");
            JButton up = new JButton("Up");
            left.addActionListener(new LeftButton());
            right.addActionListener(new RightButton());
            down.addActionListener(new DownButton());
            up.addActionListener(new UpButton());
            buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            buttonPanel.add(left);
            buttonPanel.add(down);
            buttonPanel.add(up);
            buttonPanel.add(right);

            frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panel);
            frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, buttonPanel);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setResizable(false);
            frame.setSize(500, 500);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);

            Thread player = new Thread(this);
            player.start();
            animate();
    }

    private class MyPanel extends JPanel {
            /**
             *
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                    g.setColor(Color.RED);
                    g.fillRect(x, y, 10, 10);
                    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                    g.fillRect(playerX, playerY, 10, 10);
            }
    }

    class LeftButton implements ActionListener {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    horizontalGoal = -5;
            }
    }

    class RightButton implements ActionListener {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    horizontalGoal = 5;
            }
    }

    class UpButton implements ActionListener {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    verticalGoal = -5;
            }
    }

    class DownButton implements ActionListener {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    verticalGoal = 5;
            }
    }

    /*
     * Animates the player
     */
    public void run() {
            while (true) {
                    if (horizontalGoal < 0 && playerX > 0) {
                            playerX--;
                            horizontalGoal++;
                    } else if (horizontalGoal > 0 && playerX + 20 < frame.getWidth()) {
                            playerX++;
                            horizontalGoal--;
                    }
                    if (verticalGoal < 0 && playerY > 0) {
                            playerY--;
                            verticalGoal++;
                    } else if (verticalGoal > 0 && playerY + 10 < 400) {
                            playerY++;
                            verticalGoal--;
                    }
                    try {
                            Thread.sleep(15);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (intersects()){
                            playerX = 400;
                            playerY = 350;
                    }
                    frame.repaint();
            }
    }

    private void animate() {
            boolean direction = true;
            while (true) {
                    if (y <= 100) {
                            direction = true;
                    } else if (y >= 400) {
                            direction = false;
                    }
                    if (direction) {
                            y++;
                    } else {
                            y--;
                    }
                    try {
                            Thread.sleep(15);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    frame.repaint();
            }
    }

    private boolean intersects() {
            if (x <= playerX && playerX <= x + 10 && y <= playerY
                            && playerY <= y + 10) {
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, don't link to pastebin. There is the code formatting tool in the question wizard, so please use it and include all the relevant code in the question itself, for at least two reasons: 1.in the future the link may die, so the question will be incomplete, 2. In my specific case I'm behind a proxy that is blocking pastebin, so I would like to help but I can't.

Comment: the code is kinda long that's why i used pastebin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your buttonPanel is the Problem. It is also a MyPanel which uses your own paintComponent method. So if your player should be drawn playerY = 10. It is drawn on your game panel and your buttonPanel.
Change your ButtonPanel from

```
 MyPanel buttonPanel = new MyPanel();
```

to

```
Panel buttonPanel = new Panel();
```

and your probelm is gone :-)

Comment: Or `JPanel` since that's what he's using to back `MyPanel`.

Comment: no problem. longtime coding and java experience helped me to figure it out ^^